# Ansible Conditional Variable

Tags: automation, ansible

Before i start, let me give a bit detail on my ansible directory structure

- environment

  - production                # inventory file for production servers

    - group_vars
    - host_vars
    - hosts
  - staging                   # inventory file for staging environment

    - group_vars
    - host_vars
    - hosts
- roles

  - nginx
  - mysql
  - etc
- deploy_app.yml

so right now, if i want to deploy one apps to staging, i can just simply run this playbook command:

```
ansible-playbook -i environments/staging/hosts deploy-app.yml
```

for example, i defined the path for my app1 directory in staging/group_vars/webserver to "/var/www/staging.app1.com". but i also need to deploy to the same server for app2 but with different directory. Is it possible to use conditional variable in group_vars?

So if i run:

```
 ansible-playbook -i environments/staging/hosts deploy-app.yml --extra-vars "app_name=app1"
```

it will deploy to staging server on /var/www/staging.app1.com
and:

```
 ansible-playbook -i environments/staging/hosts deploy-app.yml --extra-vars "app_name=app2"
```

it will deploy to staging server on /var/www/staging.app2.com

i know that the easiest way could just define app_dir variable when running playbook, but if possible, i prefer to define the app_name then app_dir will be used based on the specified app_name.

```
if app_name =  app1, then app_dir = /var/www/staging.app1.com

elif app_name = app2, then app_dir = /var/www/staging.app2.com
```

Please advise kindly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can template `app_dir` in your group vars:

```
app_dir: '/var/www/staging.{{ app_name }}.com'
```

If you have more app-dependent variables and they are not templatable, you can use `apps` dict in your variable files:

```
apps:
  app1:
    dir: '/var/www/app1'
    key: 'klg23sdkjfsdf'
    db_host: '127.0.0.1'
  app2:
    dir: '/opt/apps/app2'
    key: 'askjh233423444'
    db_host: '127.0.1.1'
```

and use `apps[app_name].dir` when you need app_dir and so on.

Comment: it could work but the other issue is that i also have some other variable that need to have conditional such as database ip, app key, and other variable that is different between this 2 apps. Seems like the most feasible solution for now is to split the 2 apps into its own host and group_vars

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please note that you will generally get more relevant answers if you specify all the details in the question.

Comment: Thanks. it's exactly what i am looking for. At first, i already try to use your first solution then i realized there are some variable that is different on each apps